# Which dll will be created for controllers when we do FTP publish in visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dll, visual-studio-2013, ftp

So I have successfully published my MVC website in the server though FTP mode and below will be the structure once published.

[image]

So now as you see, from the base structure of `MVC` you will find `controllers` and other extra `config` files which will be not present when you do FTP publish as they will be converted to `dll`s and will be stored in `bin`. I want know which particular `dll` will be created for these controllers and other config files because if I change any code in `controller` or update any config files say `Filter.config` or `Bundle.config` then I do not want to publish whole set of `bin` again and will publish only the required `dll`s. Any idea on this?

Comment: The name is usually partially random each time and the old one must be deleted when publishing the new one. But what you *do* know is which assemblies were not generated during publish, so you can diff each time you upload.

Comment: @jessehouwing.. so you say whenever I `publish` bin  I need to delete the one from server and then `publish`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dll will be the name of your project, double click on properties and I think on the first tab is the name of the dll and default namespace. This is dependant on how you set your project up, if you created a website rather than web application the answer will be different

**Update**

To save any confusion [here is the difference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx) between web applications and website.

**Website**
As far as i know your DLLs will have the name randomly generated when the site loads for the first time.

**Web Application**
The DLL will be the name of the project as mentioned in my first post. This can be checked by double clicking on properties in the solution explorer then going to the Application section, it will be the Assembly Name

Comment: Can you please add your answer regarding the web application? cos, I've created it as a project and not as a website but if I see my bin then I find that particular `dll` with project name!

Comment: See update. I did give my answer for a web application and not a website.